# Coefficient estimation in the heat equation

Tags: inverse, boundary-value-problem

Suppose I am am investigating heat flow using the equation:

$$\partial_{t}T=\partial_{x}(k(x)\partial_{x}T)+Q$$

where $Q$ is a constant. I am investigating on a finite interval $[0,L]$ and suppose I can make several measurements of the temperature at the edges $T(t,0)=T_{0}(t)$ and $T(t,L)=T_{L}(t)$ say. I understand that I can use this to find the function $k(x)$.

The way to do this seems to be to take the Laplace transform of the heat equation and solve the corresponding Sturm-Louville equation in the $x$ variable and to differentiate the solution multiple times to find the function $k(x)$.

Is this the basic idea for doing this? I've not really studied this before and am a bit confused with how to proceed as all the stuff on inverse problems seems to be drowning in finding a-priori bounds of things.

If anyone has any references to this I would be most grateful.

Comment: Haberman  http://en.bookfi.net/book/1447519 I haven't seen the heat coefficient like that usually it is like this. $ \frac{\partial u}{\partial t} = k \frac{\partial^{2} u}{\partial x^{2}} + Q(x)$ or   $ \frac{\partial u}{\partial t} = k \frac{\partial^{2} u}{\partial x^{2}} + Q(x,t)$

Comment: when k is a function of x, it's written as I wrote it.